# Prove that (1234) is not the product of 3-cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that ($1234$) is not the product of $3$-cycles .
The proof i found *as answer in some solution manual* was : ($1234$) is odd permutation, $3$-cycles are evens, and so is their products.

The proof i deployed was using orders: the order of ($1234$) is $4$, while the order of a product of $3$-cycles is their  $lcm$ which is $3$. Hence ($1234$) cannot be the product of $3$-cycles. is there something wrong with my answer ?

Comment: It is not indeed.  the proof in the first paragraph is right , but is not mine , i do understand it though . But the one i was questioning was my attempt in the second paragraph. Thanks to Jyri Lahtonen i was wrong , i can now see why.God bless the community !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid your argument is not correct.

Consider the 3-cycles $(123)$ and $(345)$. Their product is $(345)(123)=(12453)$ of order five.

It is also possible to get permutations of even order as a product of two 3-cycles:
$$
(123)(234)=(12)(34).
$$

The rule, $\operatorname{ord}(ab)=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord}a,\operatorname{ord} b)$, applies only, when $a$ and $b$ commute, and the cyclic groups they generate intersect trivially. Both of these assumptions hold, when $a$ and $b$ are two *disjoint* cycles.

Comment: I don't see why this contradicts the <O.P.'s argument. He only an odd permutation can't be a product of even permutations,which is true…

Comment: @Bernard: The way I read the question O.P. is not asking about that (correct) proof, but about their own argument outlined in the second paragraph. The standard proof was only given as a point of reference, I think. In other words, I think that the question *Is there something wrong with my answer?* refers to the incorrect argument relying on the order of the product of non-commuting elements still being equal to the l.c.m. of the orders of the factors.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the post – actually I interpreted ‘the proof I found…’ as the proof  found by him/herself and didn't the last paragraph.

Comment: Agree that the phrasing could be clearer, @Bernard. The way I interpreted the question makes more sense to me. We can wait for a confirmation from the OP.

Comment: Thank you  Jyri , i have missed this one, the condition of being disjoint cycles is necessary in my argument to be trues.  Thank you very much!

Comment: For an example where the specific thing the OP claimed fails (product of $3$-cycles of order $4$), one can look at $S_6$ (and no smaller symmetric group will work).

Answer (score 1):

Each 3-cycle is an even permutation, noting that (abc) = (ab)(bc) is a way of writing (abc) as a product
of two (i.e., an even number of) swaps. Thus any product of 3-cycles is also an even permutation.
But (1234) = (12)(23)(34), which demonstrates that it is odd and not even.